# Minimum distance between n points on a circular track

Tags: geometry

Assume that we have the set $N$, which consists of $n$ points on a circle or other closed 2d track, and that the distances between each point are known. From those $n$ points, distances must be measured counter-clockwise around the track. There must be some point or points $x$ $\epsilon$ $N$ that minimize $d(1,x) + d(2,x) + ... + d(n,x)$. How can I find $x$?

Examples:
 $N = [\frac {\pi} {4}, \frac {7\pi}{4}]$
In order to minimize $d(1,x) + d(2,x)$,  $x= \frac {\pi}{4}$

$N = [0, \frac \pi2, \pi, \frac {3\pi}{2}]$
To minimize $d(1,x) + d(2,x) + d(3,x) + d(4,x)$, $x=$ any point in $N$

Comment: You need to give some additional details before this is totally clear... What are the $d$'s? Are they the distance between consecutive points or what are they? Also, how can a point minimize the already known distances?

Comment: The $d$'s are the distances or arc lengths between each of the points and $x$. An example that will hopefully help: Say $n=3$ and all of these points are located in the 1st quadrant of the circle. Then placing $x$ on the most counter-clockwise point would minimize $d_1,_x + d_2,_x + d_3,_x$.

Comment: So $x$ has to lie on the circle? What do you mean with "the most counter-clockwise point". If you had two points that were closer together than $\pi$, would $x$ then lie directly in between those two?

Comment: Yes, $x$ must lie on the circle. No, $x$ would not lie directly between the two. If I have a point at $-\frac {\pi} {2}$ and another at $\frac {\pi} {4}$, placing $x$ at $\frac {\pi} {4}$ would minimize the distances.

Comment: Oh, because of the "must be measured counter-clockwise around the track", right? I think I get it now

Comment: Yes that's correct. Excellent. Sorry I wasn't more clear in the initial post.

Comment: No problem! :) If I have time, I'll look at it tomorrow, but I hope someone else will have a go at it before that. To increase the likelyhood of that, consider including the example you just told me, I think it will make things more clear. Also point out that $x$ must be on the track. Cheers!

Comment: $x$ is not always the "most clockwise point", at least not the way I interpret it. Suppose you have the points: $x_0 = 0; x_1 = \pi/2$ and then $x_2 = x_1 + \varepsilon; ... ; x_{1+n} = x_1 + n\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon>0$ is some small number. Basically, the points $x_2$ and so on, are just after the point $x_1$. In this case, $f(x_0) = (n+1)\pi/2 + n\varepsilon$. While $f(x_1) = 3\pi/2 + n\varepsilon$.
$$ $$
I'd say that $x_0$ is the most clockwise point, but if you take $n$ to be large enough, and $\varepsilon$ to be small enough, the minimum sum of distances is reached at $x_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: Since you haven't specified a particular distribution of the points, this answer focuses on finding an efficient algorithm for determining the answer given* any *distribution.*

Because of the restriction that distances are measured only in one direction, we can cut and unfold the circular track to produce a straight line. The line can begin with either of the $n$ points. 
Let $d_k$ be the distance between the $k$th and the consecutive point (note that $d_n$ is the distance between the last and first point). Now the lines can be viewed as being pieced together by the $d$'s. Note the ordering of the $d$'s: When going from investigating one starting point to the next, all we have to do is to take the piece of the line, we just investigated as the starting point, and glue it to the end of line instead, so that the whole line has been shifted.

Now we want to go about measuring how long each point is from the starting point. To see the pattern, let us take an example where $n=3$ and we put $d_1$ first. The total length is then $$L_1=d_1+(d_1+d_2) + (d_1+d_2+d_3)$$
For $n$ points this then becomes $$L_1=(n-1)d_1+(n-2)d_2+...+2{n-2}+1d_{n-1}+0d_n$$
Note that when we proceed to investigate $L_2$, all we have to do is shift the $d$'s one place to the left (and to the end, with the $0$, if it was at the beginning). This can be generalized and written in the language of matrices as

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        d_1 & d_2 & \cdots & d_{n-1} & d_n \\
        d_2 & d_3 & \cdots & d_{n} & d_1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots \\
        d_{n-1} & d_n & \cdots & d_{n-1} & d_{n-2} \\
        d_n & d_1 & \cdots & d_{n-2} & d_{n-1} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
n-1 \\ n-2 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
L_1 \\ L_2 \\ \vdots \\ L_{n-1} \\ L_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Given a list of the distances $d_k$, this list of $L_k$ (and its minimum) is easily calculated by a computer. Matlab, Octave or Mathematica are programs that handle matrix operations well, but many others will do just fine as well.

I know I took a big leap in the calculations when writing it all on matrix form, but if you are familiar with linear algebra, you can figure it out.

If there's anything that's unclear, please let me know.

---

**EDIT: Here's a Matlab program that'll do the trick:**

```
clear all; close all; clc;

n = 1000;
d = randi(100,1,n); % placing the points randomly along the track
d = d./sum(d); % array of distances that make up circle of unit length
D = zeros(n);

for i = 0:n-1 % creates the matrix with the distances
    D(i+1,:) = circshift(d,[0,-i]);
end

L = D*flipud([0:n-1]'); % calculates each scenario
k = find(L == min(L)) % finds the distance you should lay first
```

In this case it calculates the point you should be starting with (`k`) for a curve with $1000$ points on it. On my laptop it takes about 0.028 seconds. If you want to manually input the distances, just define them as you want in place of the two lines involving `d =`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your original explanation was great and the Matlab code  makes it even better.

Comment: @JPetersen Glad you liked it, it was fun to work out! May I ask what it is intended for? Just a curiosity or is it a project of some sort?

Comment: It is actually an abstraction of a practical problem I'm trying to solve. People are standing by a conveyor and putting items on it. I'll use this to find out where the optimal position for the items to come off of the conveyor is.

Comment: @JPetersen That is so cool! Thanks for letting me know!